# Is VSCode vulnerable to CVE-2020-15999?

Tags: security, visual-studio-code, freetype

As VSCode seems to contain elements of chromium (and thus FreeType), is it vulnerable to CVE-2020-15999?
This is a heap buffer overflow in FreeType < 2.10.4 with potential to remote code execution. If so, is there already a planned release date for a patch?

I know this is an unusual question for StackOverflow, but the official repository linked here via issue template, so I guess this would be the correct place to ask.

Best regards